# Absolute position a line under multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple setup, whereby I add a 2px high 'line' under all my A href's, in an :after psuedo element.

The problem is that I want that line to be under each line of text within the a html tag, not just the bottom of the a.

Is there a way to make the :after appear under each line of text, rather than the text block as a whole?

I am not using text-decoration: underline; is because I want to control the look/styling of the underline and also then animate it on hover.

HTML:

```
<a href="link.com">Some text here that will wrap onto 2 lines because it is quite long</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: currentColor;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

I want the :after line to appear under BOTH lines of text, when it wraps (so appears like a common a link underline), but current it only shows under the A block as a whole...

I want:

```
Some text that will wrap onto 2 lines 
_____________________________________

because it is quite long.
_________________________
```

What I get:

```
Some text that will wrap onto 2 lines 

because it is quite long.
           _____________
```

Comment: No, this is not possible using absolute positioning - because absolute positioned elements can not behave like `display: inline` any more, they automatically get “block” behavior, see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Answer (score 1):

ok, probably not the most elegant solution, but you can try with a gradient Background:

```
.gradientLink{  
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212121;
  padding: 14px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, red 1px, white 1px);
}
```

https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/MZGPNX

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code please.

```
 a::after{
  max-width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  content: '';
  display: block;

  }
```

It will set border after every a tag ,u can manually adjust the border width by changing **max-width** size.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I need the underline under the TEXT, not under the whole a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use border instead ?

```
a{
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
        text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: Because I'm animating the :after on hover, and I can't do that with a border.

Comment: Are you trying to animate in a way the line will go down from the text on hover ?

Comment: Doing a transform: scaleX(0); on the :after - with some easing.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot do that with pure CSS. The only solution coming to my mind at this point is to add elements/lines to the dom using javascript:

I would advice subscribing to the 'resize' event on the window and to change the amount of your needed underlines according to the number of lines your a tag takes up.

Comment: I though that was the case - subscribing to the resize event sounds messy, just for an underline, I'll try and find another solution.